# How to create a member barcode passbook pass from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, passbook, geofencing

I'm new to iOS passbook development and I'm having trouble defining the limitations of the service. I'd rather not jump into several hours of dev work that I don't have time for without knowing it will work.

### End Goal:

A user is walking to a particular location and receives a pass with their member barcode on it.

### Question:

Is it possible to create this pass from my iOS app under these assumptions without any other web service or push notification involvement?

1. The user's barcode number is passed in via a web service after first
   running the app.
2. The location coordinates are also sent in the same way.
3. There are 20+ location coordinates.

   - #1 and #2 are addressing the dynamic abilities of pass creation from an app. I'd like to know to what extent I can create a pass with a very specific member barcode that comes from the web services in the app itself.
   - #3 addresses the issue that a pass can only have 10 locations and I'm curious how to solve that issue. I suppose I could make 3 different passes (10 locations, 10 locations, X locations) but then wouldn't the user potentially have 3 passes in the passbook for what is essentially the same feature?

Answer (score 2):

Apple says pass creation needs to be done on a server, not on the device. The process involves signing the pass data with your pass certificate and you should not distribute that to devices.
I don't know how to answer your #3 question.